# Noise in beginning of alsa application

Tags: audio, ubuntu-16.04, alsa, pulse-audio

I have ALSA driver for capture device which works fine with VLC. when I try to capture and render using own application having some issues. Issue is:When I start play, it has some noise in beginning and audio is discontinuous in between. Discontinuous means, some audio frame are getting dropped in between. It looks like cut cut sound for sine wave and it continuous to play. I have tried snd_pcm_drop and snd_pcm_drain but no use.

For rendering audio I'm using aplay.c file as a reference. However, using play.c code I'm getting noise in beginning, to cross check this I have dumped application buffer and then played using aplay utility. Content in application buffer is fine. I have also confirmed with FFPlay application. FFPlay also plays with out noise. aplay [reference link](https://github.com/bear24rw/alsa-utils/blob/master/aplay/aplay.c) , and my audio render is similar to reference link.

Question:

Can you please let me know why there is noise while playing
audio in beginning

Comment: Does `aplay` itself work?

Comment: @CL, I have dumped audio data to file and then played using aplay with dumped file. aplay is working fine with dumped data in application.

Comment: So your code is not identical with aplay's. The problem is somewhere in whatever you have coded differently.

Comment: @CL, i'm sharing my audio render code , which is similar to aplay. https://github.com/chakripradeep/audiorender/blob/master/audiowithalsa.c

Comment: @CL, any ALSA API i'm missing in my code or any ALSA API needs to added to remove the noise in beginning ?

Comment: What are the values of `start_threshold` and `stop_threshold`? And why did you choose them?

Comment: start_threshold  =1 and stop_threshold = 75 bytes. I have commented start_threshold  and stop _threshold API, but still I have same issue.

Comment: Sorry, stop_threshold is 19200 for 48KHz samplerate

Comment: And why have you chosen these values?

Comment: As I said, I have taken reference code from aplay utility. I had debugged code for understanding. I really don't know why those values are required. Please tell me what is significance of those API and what values are it should contain.

Comment: @CL,If I set stop_threshold as 0 then there is no starting noise, but sine wave does not look like sine wave. content of audio is deteriorated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code attempts to read from a PCM capture device, (then probably process the data,) and then write the data to a PCM playback device.

At the beginning, when you have read, e.g., 100 samples, and then write 100 samples and start the playback, and then wait for the next 100 samples to be captured, the playback buffer will be completely empty when those next samples are available. And because your code is not infinitely fast, the playback device will then try to play a sample that is not there. This will result in an underrun, or in wrong data (depending on how you have configured the stop threshold).

To ensure that there are enough samples available for playback even while your code is executing, you should capture as much data as possible, and write it to the playback buffer, *before* you start the playback device. In other words, set the playback device's start threshold to the buffer size.

And there is no reason to change the stop threshold from its default value.

Comment: thank you for sharing above information. Information is really good for understanding. I had looked into some of your reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50103858/alsa-proper-way-to-playback-audio-blocking-mode-and-threads) . I had modified the my reference code to according into want you suggested me "set the playback device's start threshold to the buffer size." for this snd_pcm_sw_params_set_start_threshold(handle, swparams, buffer_size); . There is no sound at output after modifying start threshold to buffer size. Please share your valuable inputs.

Comment: Does your code actually fill the buffer completely?

Comment: When I debugged my alsa application, chunk_size is 75 , buffer_size is 19200, count is 75. So when I do snd_pcm_readi and writei count is 75. Perhaps,reason for noise also includes circular buffer handling in application..?

Comment: So is your loop executed 256 times?

Comment: Yes. After modifying start threshold there was no sound.

Comment: ,In below code, can you please tell me why rest is having such big number  while (rest > 0 && recycle_capture_file == 0) {
   size_t c = (rest <= (off64_t)chunk_bytes) ?
    (size_t)rest : chunk_bytes; For my application rest is same as LLONG_MAX which is very big number.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is correct value of timelimit inside calc_count() function. In my code, timelimit is set to 0,

Comment: I do not know what that code is trying to accomplish.